# Conditional tags issue for multiple is_page() conditions in sidebar.php

Tags: theme-development, sidebar, conditional-tags

I've been pulling my hair out today trying to get this right. Basically I have a sidebar, which makes requests to individual files (such as sidebar-home.php, sidebar-residential.php) and different dynamic menus are supposed to be loaded depending on what page you're on.

Previously this has been easy to set up when moving between: is_page, is_single, is_category, is_archive etc... But, as I have read, is_page keeps returning as true, despite any reset or endif condition.

Would love to hear some feedback on what I am doing wrong here. How can I get is_page(24) and is_page(36) to see different parts of the sidebar?

Code is below

```
<?php
    if ( is_page('189') ) :
        get_sidebar('home');   
    elseif ( is_page() && !is_page(array('189','24','36',is_tree('24'),is_tree('36'))) ) :
        get_sidebar('page');
    elseif ( is_page('24') && !is_page(array('36')) || is_tree('24') || is_or_descendant_tax('6','product_category') || is_or_descendant_tax('6','topic') ) :
        get_sidebar('residential');
    elseif ( is_page(array('36'))  && !is_page(array('24')) || is_tree('36') || is_or_descendant_tax('15','product_category') || is_or_descendant_tax('5','topic') ) :
        get_sidebar('utility');
    elseif ( is_post_type_archive('download_type') ) :
        get_sidebar('download');
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`is_tree` returns true or false, passing false to `is_page` will always return true. I don't think this does what you expect it to:

```
!is_page( array('189','24','36',is_tree('24'),is_tree('36')) )
```

Answer (score -1):

Part of the issue was the custom is_tree function (provided by CSS Tricks), combined with conditional tags stacking on top of each other and following tags to always return return.

My working code is below, will provide a further explanation of how it works if enough people request (sorry for all the additional php opening/closing tags in advance).

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) {   ?> 

<?php get_sidebar('home'); ?>  

<?php } if ( get_post_type() == 'downloads' ){ ?> 

<?php get_sidebar('download'); ?>   

<?php } if ( is_page('24') || $post->post_parent == '24' || is_or_descendant_tax('6','product_category') || is_or_descendant_tax('6','topic')) {   ?> 

<?php get_sidebar('residential'); ?>        

<?php } elseif ( is_page('36') || $post->post_parent == '36' || is_or_descendant_tax('15','product_category') || is_or_descendant_tax('5','topic')) {  ?> 

<?php get_sidebar('utility'); ?> 

<?php }  if (!(is_page(array('24','36')) || is_front_page() || $post->post_parent == '24' || $post->post_parent == '36' || is_or_descendant_tax('15','product_category') || is_or_descendant_tax('5','topic') || is_or_descendant_tax('6','product_category') || is_or_descendant_tax('6','topic') || is_archive('download_type'))) { ?> 

<?php get_sidebar('page'); ?>  

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't very helpful, unless you publish how does `is_or_descendant_tax` function look like.